# How to plot dynamic with calculation in Python

Tags: python, dynamic, module, plot

I want to plot a line going on with a calculation. For instance: I have got a function like `a,b = Update()`, and just below the calculation I would like to plot the newly calculated `points(a,b)`, what kind of lib should I use in Python?

```
a,b = Update()# a, b are just a float value, or maybe an array so a,b can combine to form a group of points
points(a,b)
```

I am a newly Python starter, so...

Comment: check out [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/)

Comment: Yes, use `Matplotlib`. Have 2 lists with, each storing the values. When a new value is added delete the old and create a new plot with the new data and redraw the figure.

Comment: `arrays` don't really exist in python, use lists. Arrays do exist in `Numpy` (a very useful library) but they data cannot be easily appended to them. Whereas with list you can just do: a=[1,2,3]; a.append(4)` which gives `[1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: thanks, but ideally is to plot dynamically while getting more date of points. Is there some solution?